# How to save a collection all at once in Grails

Tags: grails, collections

For example I need to retrieve several registers in a table, and edit a field, but it takes too long to save all with a loop, does exist a better way to save?
This how I do it....

```
class Table

   static mapping = {
      table "TABLEEX"
      id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'TABLEEX_SEQ']
   }

   // identificacion
   String data1
   String data2
}
```

And searching the data:

```
def stuff = Table.createCriteria().list{
   eq("data1","1")
}
```

And editing and saving

```
stuff.each {
   it.data2 = "aaa"
   it.save()
}
```

Comment: Using a `where` query will allow you to do this without making a bunch of roundtrips to the database.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't clear why you are retrieving the objects to begin with.  Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
Table.executeUpdate("update Table t set t.data2=:newData where t.data1=:oldData", [newData: 'BAR', oldData: 'FOO'])
```

**EDIT**

You could also do something like this...

```
def query = Table.where {
    data1 == 'FOO'
}
int total = query.updateAll(data2:'BAR')
```

Comment: does it support 'like' ?

Comment: Right.  The `where` query is really the way to go.  The only reason I wrote the HQL example first is that I was surprised by the comment in another answer that asserted that Hibernate doesn't support this without iterating over all of the objects, which it does.  The HQL example would work, but there are a number of reasons that the `where` query is a better idea.  Glad that helped!

Answer (score -3):

Hibernate (the underlying mechanism of gorm, the grails orm) does not support that.
You'll have to iterate over every element and save or implement it yourself (and that will not make it faster).

Comment: :(  thanks, grails is good, but it's too slow sometimes, I'll have to call an external script, thanks!

Comment: Hibernate does support updates without having to retrieve all of the instances and iterating over them.  I think you could use executeUpdate so all of the real work happens in the db and not the application.

Comment: I think using a `where` query is a better idea than writing an external script.

Comment: I dont understand the -1, there is no way to save a collection all at once and that is what I answered. There was a solution to your problem as pointed by @JeffScottBrown but that does not take away from mine...

Comment: I didn't -1 it, but the claim "You'll have to iterate over every element and save or implement it yourself..." could be read as incorrect.

Comment: If you have a collection of persistent instances and want to save them all, that may be true, but the problem as described doesn't seem to require that instances be created in the first place. The title of the question is "How to save a collection all at once in Grails" but the problem described doesn't call for a collection at all.

Comment: In any case, it isn't my -1.  I know you weren't suggesting that it was necessarily, but just to be clear.  ;)

Comment: I did -1 the other answer that has since been deleted because it made a claim that was simply false.

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure the guy with the question did it but OK, thank you for a more complete answer.